# Find Table with maximum number of rows in a database in mysql

Tags: mysql

As the question title suggests, I want to find the table having maximum number of rows (entries) in a particular database. I have been able to extract the names of all the tables in a particular database using the query below.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="Some_Database";
```

How do I proceed beyond this?? I have been trying to formulate a nested query for the above purpose but couldn't come up with something (I am not very comfortable with them). Please Help.

EDIT: As given in this [link](http://marist89.blogspot.in/2009/05/informationschematablestablerows.html) the table_rows field does not give an accurate result. That is why I need to do something like a `MAX (Count(*))` for each table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one......

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,MAX(TABLE_ROWS)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "DB_Name";
```

**OR**

please try the following two queries for actual result.

**query 1:**

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ', table_name, ' union all') 
      FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'your_db_name';
```

**query 2:**

```
select max(cnt) from (paste the result of first query and remove 
last union all keyword) as tmptable;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "Some_Database"
ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`information_schema.tables` has a column named `table_rows`, so:

```
SELECT   table_name 
FROM     information_schema.tables 
WHERE    table_schema = 'Some_Database'
ORDER BY table_rows DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can obtain the table name having max number of rows in MySQL using the this query

```
SELECT  
TABLE_NAME,MAX(TABLE_ROWS)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_Name'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME ORDER BY MAX(TABLE_ROWS) DESC LIMIT 1;
```