# ORACLE : Find table in database knowing the number of rows

Tags: database, oracle

I have a requirement I need your help with.

Number of rows in a table : 130

That is the only data I have. Based on this, Is it possible to find out the table names from an Oracle Database that contain 130 rows in them.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: if statistics are up to date, you can try to find it using the `all_tables` table and filter on the `num_rows` column.

Comment: Atleast you know the `schema`? In that case, you can do a `dynamic SQL` by fetching count of every table. It would not depend on statistics, but very costly  if table count is more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM dba_tables WHERE num_rows = 130  
-- num_rows = 130 can be replaced with any requirement you have
```

Comment: This is not reliable, depending on statistics. If stats are not up to date, this result may be wrong.

Comment: @Aleksej I answered based on the OP's needs. There are indeed a lot of constraints that might affect the final result.

Comment: @Shadow Do not forget to mark your selected answer after you are fully satisfied with one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some dynamic SQL:

```
declare
  n number;
begin
    for t in ( 
               select owner || '.' || table_name as tab
               from dba_tables
               where owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'  /* IF YOU KNOW THE SCHEMA */
              )
    loop
        execute immediate 'select count(1) from ' || t.tab into n;
        if n = 130 then
            dbms_output.put_line('Table ' || t.tab );
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Please consider that, depending on the number of tables/records in your DB, this can take very long to run.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query may help you:

**Query 1 :** SELECT CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ', table_name, ' union all') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'aes';

**Query 2:** select max(attendance)  from ( paste the results obtained from the above query and remove the last union all) as tmptable;

**Reference:**
[Find Table with maximum number of rows in a database in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737524/find-table-with-maximum-number-of-rows-in-a-database-in-mysql)